# Is it possible to use Google's "Material Web" component library in Stencil to generate React component wrappers from it?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, web-component, stenciljs

I recently embarked on a React project that involves the integration of Web Components. These Web Components are sourced from two distinct origins: the "Material Web" component library developed by Google ([material-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-web)), and a self-designed Component Library crafted using Stencil.

Both libraries are integrated as dependencies in the base React project.

Interestingly, Stencil has the capability to generate React component wrappers for the Web Components constructed with its framework.

I found myself pondering the feasibility of utilizing Google's "Material Web" component library within the Stencil framework, and subsequently, whether it is possible to derive React component wrappers from this integration.

So on a test basis, I imported the `Checkbox` component from `material-web` into a Stencil component:

```js
import { Component, h, Prop } from "@stencil/core";
import {Checkbox} from '@material/web/checkbox/lib/checkbox'

@Component({
  tag: 'material-web-checkbox',
  styleUrl: 'material-web-checkbox.css',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MaterialWebCheckbox {

  @Prop() text: string;


  render() {
    return (
        <Checkbox>{this.text}</Checkbox>
    );
  }

}
```

I generated the web components and React wrappers with Stencil and used the component in the React project:

```js
const TestComponent = () => (
  <>
    <MaterialWebCheckbox text="some text">Test Test</MaterialWebCheckbox>
  </>
);
```

I don't get any errors, but I don't see a proper Checkbox component rendered. Also the property `text` is not rendered.

Is it generally not possible to use Google's "Material Web" component library within Stencil or ma I doing something wrong?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or shared experiences on this matter, as my search for a definitive answer has thus far proven unfruitful.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping you with **your** code. This question will probably be flagged by moderators and closed. Better to ask the StencilJS team: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil

Comment: "I don't see a proper Checkbox component" suggests that your **page** does not import/load the Material Web library properly in the browser.